# How do I know the bugs in my android project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-drawable

I am using Android Studio and I am putting my final touches on the design for small, large, and xlarge layouts, but I am surprised that there are some bugs that I am not sure how to solve them.
For example:

```
Potential stack overflow trying to resolve '?attr/textColorHighlight': cyclic definitions? 
Render may not be accurate.
(3 similar error not show)
Failed to convert ?attr/textColorHighlight into ColorStateList. 
(3 similar errors not shown).
```

Any suggestions please, I am beginner in android. 
Best.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using android studio for your project building because now it is the standard IDE for building the android apps. You just need to run your app in debug mode and then later on you can open your logcat to see what is the error.

Comment: It is not coding problem I guess. ok.. would you mind to refer me to some documents I can read about the bugs in android. also, I guess this kind of a theme ?attr/textColorHighlight is couldn't solved.

Comment: yes it can be any error, it can even be theme style error, everything is logged in the logcat.. Link: https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: I wouldn't be able to attach a picture of what am trying to say because I don't have many reputations points and am very beginners in android. But the thing is not in java code rather than in xml files. would you mind to contact me on skype? this is my name : ahmed12azmi. I would share you my screen and show you where is it exactly. I would appreciate it by then.